# Get dropdown list selected value on submit and pass it to @helper in view? need more optimized way

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view

In my mvc application:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("ddllanguage", Model.Language, new {@style = "width:200px;" })

        <input type="submit" value="submit" />

    }

 <h4>@MyHelper.Translate("Welcome","EN")</h4>
```

On button submit I want to pass value of selected dropdown string to @MyHelper.Translate method instead of hardcode "EN".

Is there a way in MVC to do so? Else should I use simple `ViewData`?

set `ViewData value from controller and pass it to view`

in controller

```
  public ActionResult Index(string ddllanguage)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddllanguage))
                {
                    ViewData["languageCode"] = "EN";
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewData["languageCode"] = ddllanguage;
                }
    in View
         <h4>>@MyHelper.Translate("Welcome", "", ViewData["languageCode"].ToString())</h4>
```

> I need more optimized way , please suggest.

Comment: Does your code post back to this page?

Comment: yes it makes a post back

Comment: Perhaps `@MyHelper.Translate("Welcome", Model.Language)`? Since you are posting back your model, and your `Model.Language` should have bind to the selected value.

Comment: I can easily do it using ViewData set value to ViewData using controller and access it in View check updated question please

Comment: @JasonCidras so what you suggest on my problem which is the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your cshtml:

```
@using model Namespace.MyModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Language, model.Langauages, new {@id = "ddlLanguages", @style = "200px"})
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
}

<!-- On POST, this will display -->
@if (Request.Method.Equals("POST"))
{
    MyHelper.Translate("Welcome", model.Language)
}
```

In your controller:

```
// HTTP GET
public ActionResult Index ()
{
    return ActionResult(new MyModel());
}

// HTTP POST
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index (MyModel model)
{
    return ActionResult(model);
}
```

Comment: post call work on single Index() also, see my question that single Index() works for both , GET and post back how ?

Comment: When you initialize your page, it calls the `HttpGet` action, which will be your `public ActionResult Index()` method. When you click on your submit button, it will go to the `HttpPost` method. Your model will be passed up to your method. Once your method is called, it will return your model back to the page.

Comment: When you are using a `form`, it will look for a `HttpPost` or `HttpPut` method in your controller. Me personally, I like to keep things separated. This tends to lead to less confusion on what happens after a POST call.

Comment: But I'm doing the exactly same thing in POST that I want to do it in GET. its just for POC  sample will it be fine to use single method.

Comment: You can use the same method for both GET and POST. You will probably need to set some conditions to check the Request. Either way will work. When you post the page, MVC will look for the method name.